# TypeError at /book/2 string indices must be integers

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, I have encountered this error

**TypeError at /book/1
string indices must be integers**

I have a JSON file called book.json (seen below)

```
{
    "books":[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Unlocking Android",
          "isbn": "1933988673",
          "status": "PUBLISH",
          
        },
        .....
```

I'm trying to get  single book using id in the view

```
def show(request, id):
    with open('bookstore/books.json') as file:
        books = json.load(file)

    book = [book for book in books if book['id'] == id]

    return render(request, 'books/show.html', book)
```

The index.html template has this code

```
{% for book in books  %}
    <a href="/book/{{book.id}}"></a>       
 {% endfor %}
```

for book links

Answer (score 1):

try

```
book_dict = json.load(file)
book = [book for book in book_dict['books'] if book['id'] == id]
```

as it looks like you aren't doing the first step into the json

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but I'm getting this error "context must be a dict rather than list".

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed it using ur code snippet and by adding the context dict                     context = {'book': book}
 return render(request, 'books/show.html', context)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `books` in the context, and access the `books` key in the JSON blob:

```
def show(request, id):
    with open('bookstore/books.json') as file:
        books = json.load(file)['books']
    books = [book for book in books if book['id'] == id]

    return render(request, 'books/show.html', {'books': books})
```